# Arishadvargas - references in Vedas

Tags: vedas, mind

Arishadvarga (See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arishadvargas)) includes Krodha and Matsarya. Further these aspects of human mind are mentioned in Ramayana and later scriptures. What references are being made to these ( krodha and Matsarya) in the Rig, yajur and sama vedas?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, My Question is to get slokas on shad ripus, particularly about above shad ripus in the Vedas. I believe there may not be a direct reference.But slokas whose interpretations are clearly about anger and competitiveness aspects of mind/consciousness is  the solution for my question. I am not interested in upanishads and puranas.

Comment: The question I linked is about Shadripus in all Hindu texts including Vedas. If an answer gives references from Vedas or Upanishads or Puranas, it should be on original only. We close as duplicates don't repeat same answers and all the questions at same place. It is the answers which gave from Upanishads or Puranas. But question asks from all. So, it is a duplicate. If you are not interested in Puranas, upanishads, it's your personal opinion. Upanishads are also vedas according to many.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, I have specifically asked for direct or interpreted slokas from the three primary vedas, my intention is to get answers from experts in the three Vedas. If you read properly, I have only asked for information from specific Vedas, not even a generalised vedas. However I do have my right to ask questions. I request you not to use your privilege to quell the request for knowledge by closing questions.

Comment: Please look at the question I linked before asking me to stop using my privilege. Closing a question happens all the time on the site for moderation purposes. It doesn't mean I am stopping you to ask a question. I have already explained the goal of duplicating questions. We don't repeat same questions. That question asks for earliest source and you are asking from Vedas. There are answers explaining. If there is an answer from Vedas, it will go to the original. Logically, they are the same. Also, don't always expect everything from Vedas. Many concepts are explained in later texts.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, I accept your take on your using your privilege. So on the subject matter of my question- I certainly referred the original question and answer. Can I conclude as per your logic above, that the matter of anger and competitiveness, are not  discussed ( not even by any stretch of imagination of interpreters of Vedas) in the three primary vedas . If you say so emphatically, please close question. Else request to allow somebody to ponder on this and close after 2 weeks..

Comment: @TelErt In [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17860/4732) u will find an Atharva Veda Mantra which has indirect references to the Shad Ripus.. There each of the Ripu is associated with an animal symbolically.